# Cant set list to custom adapter in fragment

Tags: android, listview, fragment, custom-adapter

I'm trying to create listview with custom adapter, everything fine in activity class.
but fragment extended class i can not set list in my custom adapter.[image: print screen]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should pass a `Context` object as first argument of your `CustomListAdaptor`'s constructor but you are passing a `Fragment` objecy instead.
try this :

```
CustomListAdaptor customListAdaptor = new CustomListAdaptor(getActivity(), list);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in this line

```
CustomListAdapter customAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, list);
```

More specifically the keyword **this** is your problem. You are trying to pass **this** as `Context`, which works in an Activity, because Activities *have* `Context`. However, Fragments *do not*.

So you must call the parent Activity's `Context` like so:

```
CustomListAdapter customAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), list);
```